# ng-disabled on buttons, but it doesn't refresh when I change value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, button, disabled-input

I have the following buttons:

```
    <button id="facebook" type="button" ng-disabled="signing" ng-click="fblogin()">FACEBOOK</button>
    <button id="google" type="button" ng-disabled="signing" ng-click="googleLogin()">GOOGLE</button>
```

For example, when I press the Google button it does this:

```
$scope.googleLogin = function() {
    $scope.signing = true;
    document.getElementById('googleAuth').click();
};
```

My gapi doing this:

```
  gapi.load('auth2', function(){
                      // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
                      auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                        client_id: 'MY ID',
                        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
                        scope: 'email',
                        // Request scopes in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
                        //scope: 'additional_scope'
                      });
                      attachSignin(document.getElementById('googleAuth'));
                    });
```

And the button becomes disabled, which is great, because I change `$scope.signing` to TRUE.

BUT when I come back I do this: `$scope.signing = false;` and nothing changes, the button remains disabled. Why doesn't it enable itself, when I change signing to false, do I need to let the html know somehow to refresh the status of the buttons?

Comment: Enclose `$scope.signing = false;` inside a `$scope.$apply` block. That might solve the problem

Comment: If you use `$scope.signing = {"result":false}` and change your button to `ng-disabled="signing.result"` that should work.  Basically, using primitives for this as you are (bool, number, string) instead of complex types (array, object) will give unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks a lot surajck, adding a $apply, did make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Surajck, I made it work, setting it inside a $apply, just like this:

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.signing = false;
    });
```